# Unable to merge dex error when adding room dependency

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

When i add room dependencies and try to build project i am getting "unable to merge dex error".

I am adding below dependencies

```
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha1"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha1"
```

If i remove them i am able to build project successfully.
I am using android studio 3.0 stable version.

Comment: try clean and rebuild the project

Comment: @SunilP Did many times. clean and rebuild also invalid cache restart but still same problem. If i remove this dependency build get succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing "1.0.0-alpha1" with 1.0.0-rc1 solved the problem.